# Limit cycles as closed geodesics (in negatively or positively curved space)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, riemannian-geometry, foliations

**Updated 1/25/2023**  I just added  a  related post below:

[Jacobi fields, Conjugate points and limit cycle theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/439319/jacobi-equation-and-conjugate-points-on-solution-curves-of-the-van-der-pol-vecto)

**EDIT:** [Here is  a  related post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277495/limit-cycles-as-closed-geodesics2) which  concern quadratic  vector fields rather than Van der Pol equation. In this  linked  post  we  see that  the  convexity of limit  cycle  play  a  crucial role. On the  other  hand [the  unique  limit  cycle  of Van der  Pol  equation is  convex](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0007449712000899). So  there  is  a  Riemannian metric  on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus C$ such that all  solutions  of the  Van der Pol  equation are  geodesics. Here  $C$  is  the  algebraic  curve  $yP-xQ=0$  where  $P,Q$ are  the  components  of  the  Van der Pol  equation. Moreover  the  unique limit  cycle  of  the Van der Pol  equation  does  not  intersect this  algebraic  curve  $C$.

The classical Van der Pol equation is the following vector field on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$:

\begin{equation}\cases{\dot{x}=y-(x^{3}-x)\\ \dot{y}=-x}\end{equation}

This equation defines a foliation on $\mathbb{R}^{2}-\{ 0\}$. It is well known that this vector field has a unique limit cycle (isolated closed leaf) in the (punctured) plane.

I search for a geometric proof for a particular case of this fact. In fact I search for an

alternative proof of the fact that this system has **at most** one limit cycle.

Here is my question:

**Question:**

> Is there a Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^{2}-\{0\}$ with the following two properties?:
>
> 1. The Gaussian curvature is nonzero at all points of $\mathbb{R}^{2}-\{0\}$.
> 2. Each leaf of the corresponding foliation of $\mathbb{R}^{2}-\{0\}$  is  a geodesic.

Obviously from the Gauss Bonnet theorem we conclude that  existence of such metric implies that there are no two distinct  simple  closed geodesics on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}$, otherwise we  glue two copy  of the  annular region surrounded by  closed geodesics along the  boundary then we obtain a torus  with non zero curvature.(So this gives us an alternative proof for having at most one  limit cycle for the Van der Pol equation)

For  a  related question see [Conformal changes of metric and geodesics](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/220456/conformal-changes-of-metric-and-geodesics)

My initial motivation for this question goes back to more than 15 years ago, when I was reading a statement in the book of De Carmo, differential geometry of curves and surface, who wrote that:

**A topological cylinder in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$  whose  curvature is negative, can have at most one closed geodesic.**

After this, I asked my supervisor for a possible relation between limit cycles and Riemannian metrics. As  a response to my question,  he introduced me a very interesting paper by Romanovski entitled "Limit cycles and complex geometry"

My another motivation was the following: Almost at the same years of reading the above mentioned phrase in De Carmo book, I attended  a talk in Sharif university of Technology presented by Hessam Tehrani about variational problems. A particpant commented "I think existence of  closed geodesics is investigated by the same methods" His comment was a motivation for me  to consider a closed geodesic approach to limit cycle theory.

> **Note 1:** For  the  moment we  forget "negative  curvature".We  just search for  a  metric compatible  to the  Van der Pol foliation. In this regard, one can see that for every  metric on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$,   with the property that all solutions  of the Van der  Pol equations are (non parametrized)  geodesics, then either the metric  is  not  complete or the  punctured  plane  does  not  possess a polynomial  convex  function  or  an strictly convex function. This  is  a consequence  of  Proposition 2.1 of [this  paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-145-00/S0002-9947-1969-0251664-4/) and also [the  following fact](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002203968571008X).

**Note  2:** What is the answer if we replace the Van der Pol vector field by an arbitrary foliation of $\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus \{0\}$ with  a unique compact leaf?

**Remark:**  The initial motivation is mentioned in [page 3, item 5 of  this  arxiv note.](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507516)

> ** Edit Feb 1, 2020** A reference we just found whose subject is some what similar to this post:
> https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.02783

Comment: You haven't specified how the metric is related to the Van der Pol equation, so how can this provide an alternative proof?

Comment: @JaapEldering  The second point says "each leaf of the corresponding foliation of $\mathbb{R}^{2}-\{0\}$ is a geodesic. so there is a relation between the foliation arise from vander pol vec. field and the metric under my question. I am interested in this question, since many years ago. I approched to chapter "geodesiable flow" in the book"Geometry of foliation" By Tondeur. But I can find an answer to this question

Comment: Chapter 6 of that book.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that your question is simply: *Is there a negatively curved metric on the punctured plane $\mathbb{R^2}\setminus 0$ such that all solutions curves of the van der Pol equations are geodesics albeit with a possibly different parameterisation?*

Comment: @alvarezpaiva Let me explain what I mean by another example;consider the foliation of upper half plane by vertical lines. there are at least two metric such that the vertical lines are geodesic(after reparametrization) for the metric:Euclidean and Hyperbolic. The hyperbolic one has negative curvature. Now in my question, we have a cylinder $\mathbb{R}^{2}\0$ and we have a foliation via vander pol equation. we search for a metric with negative curvature such that the leaves (no mater of parametrization) are geodesics(geometrically). Now is it clear what I mean in the question?

Comment: @alvarezpaiva So any closed orbit would be a closed geodesic. Now the curvature is negative then there are NO two disjoint closed geodesic. Then Van der Pol has at most one closed orbit

Comment: @AliTaghavi:  The answer to my query is then "yes".

Comment: @alvarezpaiva I am interested in this question since 10 years ago. Is there a complet answer to this question? Is it an obvious question?

Comment: @AliTaghavi: although your approach is interesting in that case, I don't understand how you hope to relate it to Hilbert 16th's problem when there is more than 1 limit cycle…?

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier thanks for your positive opinion on this approach.. For higher number of limit cycles, a possible (generalized) approach: Is there a riemanian metric on $\mathbb{R}^{2}-\text{singularities}$ such that the points with zero curvature is a (disjoint) union of curves which are **transverse** to the vector field. **And we can controle the number of components of $\text{curvature}=0$ in term of degree of polynomial vec. field**

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier A natural question and obstruction **what about center problem** ? Ok, Lets consider a quadratic system: we know that there are a finite number of algebraic condition on coefficients of a quadratic system which completly gives us the center condition. So we hope that our metric is  a function of cooeficient of quadratic system and the curvature is either identicaly zero(at center condition) or is singular(unbounded, with bad behavior)

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier  a similar situation occured in center-focuse problem.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier Another point: note that we should **not** try the following: introduce  a metric which zero curvature points are invariant under flow: because we possibly give an explicite metric(with an explicite formula) and this shows that the limit cycles satisfies certain formula. **But a painful fact is that solutions of of a generic polynomial vector field are hardly transcendental** so we possibly should try to obtain a transverse "zero curvature points" not tangent ones.

Comment: @AliTaghavi: I'm afraid I can't tell for sure that I followed your argument. Anyway, I hope your interesting question will find an aswer.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier Thanks again for your comments. I too hope that I can find an answer.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier  Plesae see an updated in the  following post. It turn out that a  quadratic  vector  field is  geodesible.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273635/finding-a-1-form-adapted-to-a-smooth-flow/273648#273648

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier  And I think that the same  works  for the  Vander pol since its  limit cycle is  convex  hence $d\theta >0$  works.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier  In the  environment  of  this   post but with a  holomorphic  flavour one can think to the following question: To what  extent all polynomial vector fields with the following property are classified:  The regular leaves of the corresponding SHFC in $\mathbb{C}P^2$   are totally  geodesics immersed real 2 submanifolds of $\mathbb{C}P^2 $  when we equip the latter with the  Fubini study  metric.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier  I would appreciate if you look at a more flexible version of this question as follows: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323126/a-concept-weaker-than-geodesibility-of-flows-which-is-possibly-usefull-in-limit

Comment: @alvarezpaiva  Is the  Finselrian version of the  Gauss Bonnet theorem true?Is it  a  good  idea we consider a  Finslerian version of this  post(limit cycles as closed geodesics)?

Comment: There is a version (Chern, Bao and Chern), but it is not very useful.

Answer (score 2):

I think we could gerneralize the problem: the foliation determined by Van der Pol equation are formed by maximal integral curves from a vector field in the manifold M. Geodesics are second order curves, in the sense that they are projections of vector fields defined in the tangente bundle TM. Is it possible to find equivalence between both foliations ?

This problem reminds me those trated in the Gardner's book "The Method of Equivalence and Its Applications"...

Comment: thank you for your reference to Gardner book's I will look at it. Could you please more explain about your first paragraph? Are you comparing two foliations on $M$? your second foliation is the projection of a foliation of $TM \setminus M$ with geodesic flow? what metric you are considering for such geodesic flow?

Answer (score 1):

What I would try (using brute force again :) ) is the following. So if the Van der Pol vector field, call it 
$$Y=Y^1(x^1,x^2) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1} + Y^2(x^1,x^2) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2} = \Big(x^2- \big((x^1)^3 - x^1\big)\Big) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1} - x^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2},$$ defines geodesics for some metric, then since the geodesic equation is $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}\dot{\gamma} = 0$ and the solutions $\gamma(t)$ of Van der Pol satisfy $\dot{\gamma} = Y(\gamma)$, then we are looking for a Riemannian metric $\big(g_{ij}(x^1,x^2)\big)$ whose Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ satisfies the equations $\nabla_Y\, Y = 0.$ In addition to that we want the tensor $g_{ij}$ to be (i) positive definite on the punctured plane and (ii) to have strictly negative Gaussian curvature on the punctured plane:
$$K = -\frac{1}{E} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}\Gamma_{12}^2 - \frac{\partial}{\partial x^2}\Gamma_{11}^2 + \Gamma_{12}^1\Gamma_{11}^2 - \Gamma_{11}^1\Gamma_{12}^2 + \Gamma_{12}^2\Gamma_{12}^2 - \Gamma_{11}^2\Gamma_{22}^2\right) < 0.$$

Let's look at $\nabla_Y\, Y = 0,$ which written in coordinates is

$$Y^1\frac{\partial Y^1}{\partial x^1} + Y^2\frac{\partial Y^1}{\partial x^2} + \Gamma^{1}_{1 1}(Y^1)^2 + 2 \Gamma^{1}_{12} \, Y^1 Y^2 + \Gamma^{1}_{22}(Y^2)^2 = 0$$
$$Y^1\frac{\partial Y^2}{\partial x^1} + Y^2\frac{\partial Y^2}{\partial x^2} + \Gamma^{2}_{1 1}(Y^1)^2 + 2 \Gamma^{2}_{12} \, Y^1 Y^2 + \Gamma^{2}_{22}(Y^2)^2 = 0.$$ The unknowns are the Christoffel symbols, which depend on the metric and it's first partial derivatives. I guess you do have some degree of freedom. To add more degrees of freedom, one can even consider reparametrization of $Y$ by multiplying it to an unknown nonzero function $\lambda=\lambda(x^1,x^2).$ Maybe to simplify the equations above, one can consider a diagonal metric, i.e. $g_{12}(x^1,x^2) \equiv 0$. I don't know... maybe it could work, but it looks like a lot of computations.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I wonder why this argument should not be applicable for higher degree Lienard equation (when we replace $x^{3}-x$ by a higher degree polynomial. Note that higher defrees polynomials can have more thatn "one " limit cycle, i.e geodesic. Are there some special facilities for the particular third degree?Are there some obstructions for higher degrees?

Comment: I mean that: to what extent your guess on "degrees of Freedom" is based on the particular case $x3−x$? As I said in the previos comment, we should not expect this degree of freedom for higher degree for example for $x5−x3+\epsilon x$  because in this case we have 2 limit cycles, so the global negative curvature is not possible.

Comment: I can only guess, as I haven't done any attempts to bring this idea any further, but one might be able to solve  the system of two equations for the Christoffel symbols in more general situations, like higher degree Lienard equation for instance, since everything is in the ring of polynomials. However, do not forget that this system provides just a connection. After that one needs to show that the metric corresponding to this connection is in fact a metric (positive definite) and then check the inequality $K < 0$ which for general Lienard systems might not be satisfied.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that one may get a metric in a very general context of polynomial vector fields, but this metric is rarely negatively curved.

Answer (score -4):

good question !

i have found the proof of the fact that this system has at most one limit circle in the following 2 papers :

1. http://arxiv.org/pdf/chao-dyn/9705006.pdf
2. http://dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/107715/ArchMathRetro_036-2000-1_4.pdf

your questions are :

Is there a Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^{2}-\{0\}$ with the following two properties?:

1. The Gaussian curvature is negative at all points of $\mathbb{R}^{2}-\{0\}$.
2. Each leaf of the corresponding foliation of $\mathbb{R}^{2}-\{0\}$  is  a geodesic.

you can also find the solution to your 2 questions in papers 1 (question 2 is a result directly follows from question 1)

since the van der pol equation is the special case of Li´enard equation, so if you want to generalize this problem to arbitrary polynomial vector fields, it seems that you can define a metric that satisfy the Lienard equation:

$\dot{x}=y-F(x), $$ \dot{y}=-g(x)$

you can get some tips for how to construct it from paper 2 (main theorem, page 25 )

Comment: thanks for the links. I did not find, in these 2 papers, some thing related to the curvature. could you please more explain on your answer?