# Unit eigenvalue of the linearized Poincare return map

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems

Consider a surface $S$ and a vector field on the surface which has a closed orbit. The vector field on both sides of the closed orbit spirals towards it, which gives us that the linearized Poincare return map has eigenvalue $\leq 1$. What additional information do I need to infer that the eigenvalue is strictly less than 1? I know that in a neighborhood of the closed orbit, the Gaussian curvature is negative. How are such conclusions generally made? Thanks a lot!

Edit after Ali Taghavi's comment: The integral curves of the vector field near the closed orbit have their accelerations ${\bf parallel}$ to the surface (this is kind of opposite of a geodesic).

Comment: In your question, you did  not assume  any  compatibility between your  vector field  and riemannian  structute, so why you expect that the  curvature effect on the dynamics? any way may  be a  paper By Romanovski "Limit  cycle and  complex geometry" could  be indirectly related to your question. I was interested in such  geometric compatibility in the following post:http://mathoverflow.net/questions/160945/limit-cycles-as-closed-geodesicsgeodesible-flow

Comment: please google "Limit cycles and  complex geometry" the PDF of this  paper is  availlable in the webb.

Comment: @AliTaghavi Good point regarding the compatibility. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @AliTaghavi Unfortunately googling reveals a paper written in Russian. Where can I locate an English version? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have  a PDF  file of the english version. if you wish i can email you.