# Counting limit cycles via curvature in Riemannian geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, riemannian-geometry, limit-cycles

In this post we would like to give  a possible new approach to the second part of the [Hilbert 16th problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_sixteenth_problem)

First we give  a short introduction:

A quadratic  system is  a  polynomial vector  field on the plane in the form $$(X_{\alpha})\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\begin{cases}\dot x=P_{\alpha}(x,y)\\  \dot y=Q_{\alpha}(x,y) \end{cases}$$

where  $P_{\alpha},Q_{\alpha}$  are polynomials of degree $2$  which are  parametrized by a $10$ tuple parameter $\alpha$ of  coefficients.

A  **center** is  a  singularity of this  vector  field which is  surrounded by a band of closed orbits.

All quadratic vector fields  with center are classified as  follows:

They correspond to a  finite  number of  algebraic conditions in $\alpha$,
see ["Integrability of plane  quadratic vector fields" Expos. Math(1990)3-25.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/246484433_Integrability_of_plane_quadratic_vector_fields).

We  denote these algebraic  conditions by $Cent(\alpha)=0$

**Question:**

> Are there  a  family of (polynomial) Riemannian  metrics $g_{\alpha}$ on the punctured plane(after removing singularities) with  Gaussian curvature $\kappa_{\alpha}$ with the following properties:
>
> The  solutions of $X_{\alpha}$,  after  a  possible  reparametrization,  are geodesics of $g_{\alpha}$.Moreover $\kappa_{\alpha}$, is  not  zero except at a  finite  number of  algebraic curves transverse to  $X_{\alpha}$. Moreover $\kappa_{\alpha}$  is  identically  zero if  $Cent(\alpha)=0$? The question, in particular its  last part is  well  behaved and  consistent  since a  quadratic system can not have  a  center  and  a  limit cycle, simultaneously.

If the  answer would  be  yes, [then $H(2)$, the maximum  number of  limit  cycles  of  a  quadratic system,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_sixteenth_problem)  would  be  finite.

This  question is  already  discussed at the comment-conversation of  the  following post:

[Limit cycles as closed geodesics(in negatively curved space)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160945/limit-cycles-as-closed-geodesicsin-negatively-curved-space)