# A non vanishing vector field compatible to a Riemannian metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

Assume that $(M, g)$  is  a  connected  Riemannian manifold which  is  either open or  is  compact  with zero Euler  characteristic.

> Is there  a  non  vanishing  vector  field  $X$ on $M$  such that all trajectories of  $X$ are  geodesics, after a possible  reparametrization?

The  question is  somehow a  converse  question to the  following  question:

[Limit cycles as closed geodesics(in negatively or positively curved space)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160945/limit-cycles-as-closed-geodesicsin-negatively-or-positively-curved-space)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If that would be the case, then $M$ would have a foliation by geodesics. The article

*Zeghib, A.*, [**On continuous geodesic foliations of hyperbolic manifolds**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01232666), Invent. Math. 114, No.1, 193-206 (1993). [ZBL0789.57019](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0789.57019).

shows that for a closed hyperbolic $3$-manifold there is even no continuous foliation.

A simpler example (with a non-compact manifold) is a metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ obtained by smoothing the vertex of a cone with the angle $< \pi$ at the vertex. There, geodesics far away from the vertex are self-intersecting.

Comment: Thank  you  for  your  very  interesting  answer  and the  paper  by Abdel Ghani  Zeghib.