# Limit cycles of quadratic systems and closed geodesics(Finitness of $H(2)$)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, curvature, limit-cycles

This question is  inspired by [this  answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273635/finding-a-1-form-adapted-to-a-smooth-flow/273648#273648) to the  question [Finding a 1-form adapted to a smooth flow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273635/finding-a-1-form-adapted-to-a-smooth-flow).

Assume that $V$ is  a polynomial  vector  field  of  degree $2$ as  follows:$$\begin{cases} x'=P(x,y)\\y'=Q(x,y) \end{cases}\;\;\;\;(V)$$
where $P(x,y),Q(x.y)$ are  polynomials of  degree $2$ in $x,y$ with $P(0,0)=Q(0,0)=0$.

We  define  the planar  algebraic  curve $$C=\{(x,y) \mid yP-xQ=0\}$$

The  above linked answer  shows  that:

> There  is  a  Riemannian  metric $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus  C$  such that the  trajectories of $V$ are  geodesics  with respect  to the  metric $g$. That is  $V$ is  a  geodesible vector  field on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus  C$.

Now  my  question is  that:

> Is there  a  Riemannian metric  $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus  C$ with  curvature $\kappa$  such that the  following  two properties  hold?

> 1. Trajectories of  $V$ are  (unparametrized) geodesic.

> 2. Either the curvature $\kappa$  is identically zero, correspending to "center singularity", or the set  $\{(x,y)\mid \kappa(x,y)=0\}$, is  transverse to the  vector field $V$?
>    If the  answer is   yes,  what  is  a  precise formulation  for  this  metric? (Precise  formulation of  the  metric  in terms of  $P,Q$).

According to the method of Proof of Proposition 6.7 and 6.8 in [Page  71](https://books.google.com/books?id=8DZZSsa14ncC&pg=PA71) of the book "Geometry of Foliation" By Phillip Tondeur,  it seems that a relevant(but  not  necessarily unique) metric we are searching for, should has the orthonormal frame $\{\frac{1}{\chi(V)}V,E\}$ where $V$ is the above quadratic vector field $V $,  $E$ is an arbitrary direction parallel to the radial vector field $x\partial_x + y\partial_y$  and  $\chi$ is $$\chi=\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}(ydx-xdy)$$  Notice  that $E$ lies in the kernel of the $1-$ form $\chi$.

So it seems that one can control the number of limit cycles of a typical quadratic vector field by the number of connected components which are determined by the complement of curves $yP-xQ=0$ and $\kappa=0$.
Please see the above linked answer.

> Are there  some  other metric, not  necessarily associated with the  above frame $\{\frac{1}{\chi(V)}V,E\}$, for  which the  vector  field $V$ is  a  geodesible  vector  field?Is there a  conformal one?

In fact the motivation is that, we  would  like  to  find  a  procedure to count the number of [limit  cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_cycle) of  a (typical)  quadratic  vector  field $(V)$. A procedure based on the  curvature  sign and Gauss Bonnet theorem.

Please see [this question  for further explanation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160945/limit-cycles-as-closed-geodesicsin-negatively-or-positively-curved-space).

**Remark:**  The initial motivation is mentioned in [page 3, item 5 of  this  arxiv note.](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507516)