# Flat Riemannian metrics adapted to quadratic vector fields with center

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, curvature

Assume that $P(x,y),Q(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ are two polynomials of degree $2$ with $P(0,0)=Q(0,0)=0.$
Suppose  that the vector field $$\begin{cases} x'=P(x,y)\\ y'=Q(x,y) \end{cases}$$ has a center singularity at the origin. This means that the origin is surrounded by a band of closed orbits.

> Is there a Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus  C$  with zero curvature such that all closed orbits of the vector field are closed geodesics?
>   Here $C$ is the algebraic curve $$C=\{(x,y)\mid yP(x,y)-xQ(x,y)=0\}$$

The motivation comes from the idea of consideration of "Limit cycles" of polynomial vector fields as "Closed Geodesics"  of a Riemannian metric on the phase space.
This situation is discussed in the following MO posts and item 5 of page 3 of the [this  preprint.](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507516)

[Finding a 1-form adapted to a smooth flow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273635/finding-a-1-form-adapted-to-a-smooth-flow/273648#273648)

[Limit cycles of quadratic systems and closed geodesics(Finitness of $H(2)$)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275823/limit-cycles-of-quadratic-systems-and-closed-geodesicsfinitness-of-h2)

[Limit cycles as closed geodesics(in negatively or positively curved space)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160945/limit-cycles-as-closed-geodesicsin-negatively-or-positively-curved-space?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I find it surprising, and highly interesting, that problems concerning polynomial vector fields in dimension 2, which are vector fields that can each easily be drawn, remain open to this date. I am not very familiar with the literature, but I know that Date had classified the homogeneous quadratic fields in dimension 2. Perhaps the quadratic vector fields vanishing at the origin have also been classified by now? I mean, in principle, you are only adding a linear vector field to the homogeneous quadratic one, but I suspect the classification to be very tedious. Just a small question/comment.

Comment: @Malkoun  Thank  you  for  your  comment. While  a  homogeneous quadratic  vector  field  does  not  have  a  limit  cycle, but I think that the  problem for  a general  quadratic  system is still open.That is it is open to  decide whether $H92)$ is finite  or  no?

Comment: Sorry I  revise the  comment  ....H(2)  is finite  or  no?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't been following the literature surrounding this problem.

Comment: @Malkoun  But I  am (almost)  sure  that the  problem is open even for  n=2 (quadratic  vector  field).

Comment: Ok. My interest in these quadratic vector fields was from another point of view. I wanted to find such vector fields for which the flow never blows up in finite time. They are rare but they exist. I suppose one may try to classify the quadratic vector fields vanishing at the origin, maybe under some assumptions, but this is a very tedious way to approach the problem you are interested in. Perhaps a less brute-force approach would be desirable, such as the one you are attempting.

Comment: @Malkoun  If  i  am  not  mistaken  you  are  interested in the  problem of  "Completeness" or  Non  completeness  of  polynomial vector  fields(Of  degree 2). Yes? If it is  the  case,  I  think the  following  paper  completely  classify  such  vector  fields      http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022039686901130/pdf?md5=44796f6a42b1171089e1d32865e148c6&pid=1-s2.0-0022039686901130-main.pdf&_valck=1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62715/discussion-between-malkoun-and-ali-taghavi).