# Is a non vanishing holomorphic vector field necessarily a geodesible vector field?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

Motivated by the  "**The obvious  Fact**" part of [this  answer,](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273635/finding-a-1-form-adapted-to-a-smooth-flow/273648#273648), we ask the  following  question:

First we recall  a  definition, which is  used in the  above  link:

**Definition:** A  non vanishing vector  field  $V$ on  a  manifold  $M$ is  a  geodesible vector  field if there is  a  Riemannian metric  $g$ on $M$ such that 
all trajectories of  $V$ are (unparametrized) geodesics  with respect to $g$.

> Assume that $U$ is an open subset  of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $V:U \to \mathbb{C}^n$ is  a non vanishing  holomorphic  function. This  holomorphic function $V$ defines  a  natural  vector  field on $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2n}$. (Here we  identify $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ with $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$). Is $V$ necessarily a  geodesible  flow?

**Remark:** The  concept "geodesible  flow" can be used to  count the  number of  limit  cycles  of  a planar vector field. In this regard please see the  following posts:

[Flat Riemannian metrics adapted to quadratic vector fields with center](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277085/flat-riemannian-metrics-adapted-to-quadratic-vector-fields-with-center)

[Limit cycles of quadratic systems and closed geodesics(Finitness of $H(2)$)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275823/limit-cycles-of-quadratic-systems-and-closed-geodesicsfinitness-of-h2?noredirect=1&lq=1)