# Obstructions for a foliation to be transformed to a Frenet foliation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, foliations

Assume that we have a $1$ dimensional foliation of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is there a global diffeomorphism of the plane which maps all leaves of the foliation to curves with non zero curvature?
One can consider the same question for a $1$ dimensional foliation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ requiring that  all  leaves to be transform ed to Frenet curves.

A motivation for this question:

When I was thinking to the following question, I was thinking to the orthonormal frame $\{\gamma',\gamma'' \}$ as a possible resolution to find a metric compatible to our vector field:

[Limit cycles as closed geodesics(in negatively or positively curved space)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160945/limit-cycles-as-closed-geodesicsin-negatively-or-positively-curved-space)

Answer (score 1):

Restrict the standard foliation of $\mathbb R^2$ by horizontal lines to the open subset $$U:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\mid y^2\le 1+x^2-x^4\}.$$ Clearly, $U$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$. But I don't think that there exists a diffeomorphism which maps all the leaves to curves without inflection points.

Comment: Thanks for  your answer. Can a  bioholomorphic  maps  in the plane  carry $y=x^2$  to $y=x^3$? I mean that: is  not the  Riemann mapping theorem an obstruction for  your  statement?

Comment: The only biholomorphic maps $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ are of the form $z\mapsto az+b$, but there exist many diffeomorphisms $\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$.

Comment: I  mean locally (not  necessarily  global bioholomorphism).

Comment: Yes, locally this is possible: both a real analytic curves, and any real analytic diffeomorphism between these curves extends to a holomorphic diffeomorphism between neighbourhoods of these curves. That's called analytic continuation.