# Ergodicity of geodesic flow in negative curvatutre as a possible obstruction for consideration of limit cycles as closed geodesics(4)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, negative-curvature, closed-geodesic

Does the  ergodicity of  geodesic  flow  of  compact  surfaces with negative  curvature  stile hold for  non compact  case?

Is not the  ergocity theorems of  geodesic  flow an obstruction to  have  a  cylinder  with negative  curvature  which  is  foliated by  geodesics  such that there is  a  unique closed curve for this  foliation?

**Motivation:** More  than 15 years ago  I heard from some one who said me you can not reach the  following aim because of  ergodicity of  geodesic flow  in negative  curvature

[Limit cycles as closed geodesics(in negatively or positively curved space)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/160945/limit-cycles-as-closed-geodesicsin-negatively-or-positively-curved-space?rq=1)

But I  do not  see  why  this  is  realy  an obstruction?

Answer (score 3):

The geodesic flow on (possibly noncompact) hyperbolic surfaces of finite type is ergodic. The original reference for this is [E. Hopf: „Fuchsian groups and ergodic theory“ Trans. AMS 39, 299-314 (1936)](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1936-039-02/S0002-9947-1936-1501848-8/S0002-9947-1936-1501848-8.pdf).

In negative curvature, there is only one closed geodesic in each free homotopy class of curves. So you can not have more than one closed geodesic in a cylinder. (This is not related to ergodicity, I guess.)

Comment: Thank you and +1 for  your  answer. As you said,  the  uniqueness of  closed geodesic is  not related to curvature. it is a  result of Gauss Bonnet Theorem. But in my question I search for this possible  obstruction: Is ergodicity of  geodesic  flow a possible  obstruction to have  a negatively  curved  cylinder with  a  foliation by  geodesic with AT LEAST(so exactly) one  closed geodesic.

Comment: BTW, as an independednt question, is  ergodicity of  geodesic  flow special to negative  curvature?I  mean that is there a  (compact) manifold  whose  geodesic  flow is  ergodic but its  curvature is not negative?